# Unable to borrow an iterator as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

I'm writing a simple tokenizer in Rust but I'm having trouble. I've simplified the code a bit for the sake of this question:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;
use std::str::Chars;

struct Example<'a> {
    it: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Example<'a> {
    fn tokenize_string(&mut self) {
        loop {
            match self.it.peek() {
                None => break,
                Some(_x) => self.it.next(),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.it` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
11 |             match self.it.peek() {
   |                   ------- first mutable borrow occurs here
12 |                 None => break,
13 |                 Some(_x) => self.it.next(),
   |                             ^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
14 |             };
   |             - first borrow ends here
```

I've been able to work around this by creating a copy of the iterator and calling `peek()` on that:

```
fn tokenize_string(&mut self) {
    loop {
        let mut iterator = self.it.clone();
        match iterator.peek() {
            None => break,
            Some(_x) => self.it.next(),
        };
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this?  It seems a little hack-ish.

Comment: This is a shortcoming in Rust right now:  See https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/396.  Another workaround would be to `let m = self.it.peek(); match m {`

Comment: @McPherrinM: I think this is worth an answer :)

Comment: @McPherrinM, I don't think `let m = self.it.peek()` works since the problem is `peek` returns a reference into `self.it`.

Comment: I didn't put it as an answer because I didn't know if I was right.  Not sure what the SO-ish thing to do here is.

Comment: @dbaupp is right, I tried that and it still gave me the same error.  If you want to try it out, the entire file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/JamesOwenHall/2ec6e2c24f8b37009ab0).  You'll notice that the `tokenize_string` function is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're working with `str::chars()`, and `char` is `Copy`, you can dereference to get a `char` instead of `&char`. :

```
fn tokenize_string(&mut self) {
    loop {
        let r = self.it.peek().cloned();
        let n = match r {
            Some(_) => self.it.next(),
            None => break,
        };
        // whatever
    }
}
```

If you just want to check if the iterator has returned something, use `is_some()`:

```
let r = self.it.peek().is_some();
if r { ... } else { ... }
```

In general, however, I'm not sure if it is possible exactly in this manner without non-lexical lifetimes. You will need to put the code which checks iterator state and the code which works with the iterator based on the state with scopes, something like this:

```
let r = {
    // work with self.it
};
if r { ... } else { ... }
```

Here any references into `self` must not escape the lexical block in `r`, so there is no direct `match` on a value which contains references into `self`. There's further examples of working around this in [Rust borrow of a HashMap lasts beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423).

Comment: Actually, it seems like my code is working.  All I'm doing with the copied iterator is calling `.peek()`.  I'm not trying to advance the iterator at that step, so it shouldn't matter if they're independent.  And no, I don't just want to check if the iterator returned something, this is just a simplified version of the function.  You can see the whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/JamesOwenHall/2ec6e2c24f8b37009ab0).

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, somehow I missed that it was only peek. Anyway, I still think that duplicating iterators is not a good idea, and certainly not idiomatic.

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm trying to figure out what the idiomatic way is.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesHall, I'm pretty sure that my answer qualifies for that :)