# Why doesn't the lifetime of a mutable borrow end when the function call is complete?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a bot for halite.io, and am having issues understanding some of the effects of borrowing. Here is the code that will not compile:

```
let scanLoc = hlt::types::Location {
    x: oflow(coord.0 + l.x as i32, game_map.width),
    y: oflow(coord.1 + l.y as i32, game_map.width),
};
let scan = game_map.get_site(scanLoc, types::STILL);
if (&scan.owner != id) | (scan.owner != 0u8) {
    let ang = game_map.get_angle(l, scanLoc);
    debug!("angle b/w: {}", ang);
    return (l, 2);
}
```

This is the compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*game_map` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/MyBot.rs:112:27
      |
  110 |             let scan = game_map.get_site(scanLoc, types::STILL);
      |                        -------- mutable borrow occurs here
  111 |             if (&scan.owner != id) | (scan.owner != 0u8) {
  112 |                 let ang = game_map.get_angle(l, scanLoc);
      |                           ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
  ...
  116 |         }
      |         - mutable borrow ends here
```

This is the code for the `GameMap` functions and struct:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct GameMap {
    pub width: u16, // Number of columns.
    pub height: u16, // Number of rows.
    pub contents: Vec<Vec<Site>>,
}

impl GameMap {
    pub fn in_bounds(&self, l: Location) -> bool {
        // ...
    }
    pub fn get_distance(&self, l1: Location, l2: Location) -> u16 {
        // ...
    }
    pub fn get_angle(&self, l1: Location, l2: Location) -> f64 {
        // ...
    }
    pub fn get_location(&self, l: Location, d: u8) -> Location {
        // ...
    }
    pub fn get_site(&mut self, l: Location, d: u8) -> &mut Site {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Why does Rust borrow the function mutably, and even if it is borrowing the function would it not return the borrow (ending the lifetime) when returning the result, so it would be available to borrow afterwards?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question, you are expected [to perform a good amount of research *before* asking a quesiton](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/155423). For example, there are [**77 existing questions with the same error message**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+immutable+because+it+is+also+borrowed+as+mutable+is%3Aq). Perhaps you could further [edit] your question to explain why this question is different than all of those?

Comment: The question is why the pure function calls act as mutuable borrow,  and why the borrow's lifetime extends past just that one line. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not sure you've read the error message thoroughly. It says that `game_map` is borrowed mutably because of the call to `get_site`, which you didn't include in the code (and I've edited in). See [MCVE] for further information about how to present code in a question. I'm not sure how to answer the question "Why does Rust borrow [a method that requires a mutable reference to `self`] mutably" in a meaningful way.

Comment: First, you're absolutely incredible for finding the method and adding it. Second, and more importantly, why wouldn't the lifetime of the borrow end at the end of the function call? So it would be available to borrow afterwards?

Comment: @Zarkoix: I agree, he's incredible ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Editor's note: This specific problem has been solved by the introduction of [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes).

Let's look at a tiny reproduction:

```
struct Site {
    owner: u8,
}

struct GameMap {
    site: Site,
}

impl GameMap {
    fn do_anything(&self) {}

    fn get_site(&mut self) -> &mut Site {
        &mut self.site
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut game_map = GameMap {
        site: Site { owner: 0 },
    };
    let site = game_map.get_site();
    game_map.do_anything();
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `game_map` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
21 |     let site = game_map.get_site();
   |                -------- mutable borrow occurs here
22 |     game_map.do_anything(); // Compiler error!
   |     ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
23 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

Our `GameMap` only owns a single `Site`, but that's enough. The call to `get_site` **returns a reference** (in this case it happens to be mutable):

```
fn get_site(&mut self) -> &mut Site
```

Thanks to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), this is the same as

```
fn get_site<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Site
```

This means that the returned reference is allowed to point to something inside of `GameMap` (which it does). Then we keep that reference in a variable - `site`!

That means that we can no longer use any immutable references to `game_map` as they might have been (or will in the future be) invalidated by the changes that can be made to the map through the mutable reference:

> - At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.
> - References must always be valid.

— [The Rust Programming Language chapter on references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references)

> Why does Rust borrow the function mutably, and even if it is borrowing the function would it not return the borrow (ending the lifetime) when returning the result, so it would be available to borrow afterwards?

Rust borrows your **struct** mutably because you are calling a method that requires a mutable reference (`&mut self`). That method then returns a mutable reference, transferring the borrow of the struct to the returned value. The borrow ends when the returned value goes out of scope.

---

So, how do you fix it? Probably the most flexible solution is to introduce a *scope* to constrain the mutable borrow:

```
let zhu_li_do_the_thing = {
    let site = game_map.get_site();
    site.owner == 5 || site.owner == 42
};

if zhu_li_do_the_thing {
    game_map.do_anything();
}
```

Another is the same idea, but requires that you never store the borrow in a variable at all. Thus the mutable borrow doesn't last beyond that statement:

```
if game_map.get_site().owner == 42 {
    game_map.do_anything();
}
```

It's common for idiomatic Rust code to have `foo` and `foo_mut` variants of a method, for when you don't need mutability. This may not help if you need to mutate `game_map` while the immutable borrow of `site` is still outstanding.

```
fn get_site(&self) -> &Site {
    &self.site
}

fn get_site_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Site {
    &mut self.site
}
```

```
let site = game_map.get_site();
if site.owner == 5 || site.owner == 42 {
    game_map.do_anything();
}
```

See also:

- [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423)
- [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423)

Comment: This answer would have helped me immensely had I seen it about 9 months ago! Great answer yet again Shepmaster (thumbsup)