# What is the impact of the return type in a function with a mutable borrow?

Tags: rust

The following code in Rust builds and runs:

```
fn func(s: &mut String) -> i32 {
    s.push_str("!");
    println!("{}", s);
    1
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("hello world");
    let v = func(&mut x);
    println!("{}", v);
    let r = &x[..];
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

If the return type of `func` is changed to `&str`, I get

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
9  |         let v = func(&mut x);
   |                           - mutable borrow occurs here
10 |         println!("{}", v);
11 |         let r = &x[..];
   |                  ^ immutable borrow occurs here
12 |         println!("{}", r);
13 |     }
   |     - mutable borrow ends here
```

I know that in a given scope, only one mutable reference is allowed, but how does the return type matter?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [Why doesn't the lifetime of a mutable borrow end when the function call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40578224/155423) but I already used and withdrew my gold badge dupe-hammer. Let me know when this has been closed as a dupe and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question is basically a duplicate of [Why doesn't the lifetime of a mutable borrow end when the function call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40578224/155423) but I already used and withdrew my gold badge dupe-hammer. Let me know when this has been closed as a dupe and I'll delete this answer.

---

If you don't return a reference, there can be no borrow.

> If the return type of `func` is changed to `&str`

Then, due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), the function is equivalent to:

```
fn func<'a>(s: &'a mut String) -> &'a str
```

And the returned value is allowed to borrow from the argument. Thus you can no longer change the argument in case it invalidates the return value.

If the returned value *didn't* borrow from the argument, you can use lifetimes to disentangle them. Here we return a `'static` string:

```
fn func(s: &mut String) -> &'static str {
    ""
}
```

See also:

- [Why doesn't the lifetime of a mutable borrow end when the function call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40578224/155423)
- [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is lifetime elision in very simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325690/what-is-lifetime-elision-in-very-simple-terms)

Comment: It might be worth making it clear that introducing another lifetime parameter, `fn func<'a, 'b>(s: &'a mut String) -> &'b str` could fix it?