# A borrow checker problem with a loop and non-lexical lifetimes

Tags: rust

This program that I minified from my actual program doesn't compile, and I'm unable to understand why. In my mind, the non-lexical lifetime support should have obviated this case. Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something?

The point is that when a borrow happens with the call to `get`, it leads to a `State` that is borrowed from `self`. However, in case of `State::One`, the borrow should end and the next loop should be free of borrows. (According to my understanding of NLL, it should support these cases.) On the other hand, in case of `State::Two` a value originally borrowed from `self` is returned. The function signature states this is the case, and there shouldn't be any problem with that, as the loop terminates with the return `self` isn't used anymore.

A playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da8ca1dd9d5449eb1a6903d9a1e7ae41

```
struct Inner;

enum State<'a> {
    One,
    Two(&'a ()),
}

fn get<'s>(_inner: &'s mut Inner) -> State<'s> {
    unimplemented!()
}

struct Outer {
    inner: Inner,
}

impl Outer {
    pub fn read<'s>(&'s mut self) -> &'s () {
        loop {
            match get(&mut self.inner) {
                State::One => (), // In this case nothing happens, the borrow should end and the loop should continue
                State::Two(a) => return a, // self.inner ought to be borrowed for 's, that's just to be expected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "non-lexical" doesn't mean that the borrow checker can understand every possible invariant of your system in order to prove that a borrow is safe. It just means it is not _only_ constrained by lexical scope, as it was before. The term isn't particularly useful now that it is the default behaviour of the typechecker.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519147/double-mutable-borrow-error-in-a-loop-happens-even-with-nll-on

Comment: The other question answers this question, but apparently marking it so makes me unable to send another answer (a workaround) to this question. I'm answering there to document the workaround.