# Borrow returned in one branch overlaps with borrow in other branch

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct with an `Option` used to lazily initialise a field via a getter method.

Here's my simplified code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52255a8ffc2ae6241580d61e7b8e4bbf)):

```rust
struct Worker {
    worktree: Option<PathBuf>, // Access via get_worktree    
}

impl Worker {
    fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
        if let Some(ref path) = &self.worktree {
            // Already initialized, just return
            return Ok(path);
        }
        
        // First call, initialize lazily and return.
        let path = PathBuf::from("<result of a fallible process>");
        self.worktree.insert(path);
        Ok(self.worktree.as_ref().unwrap())
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.worktree` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
9  |     fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
   |                     - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
10 |         if let Some(ref path) = &self.worktree {
   |                                 -------------- immutable borrow occurs here
11 |             // Already initialized, just return
12 |             return Ok(path);
   |                    -------- returning this value requires that `self.worktree` is borrowed for `'1`
...
17 |         self.worktree.insert(path);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I read this as: the borrow that I return in the initial conditional is treated as overlapping with the mutable borrow that's necessary to insert the new value into the `Option`.

I suppose this is because once it's return from the function, that reference must be assumed to live as long as the `Worker`, so the borrow checker forbids any mutable reference to `Worker::worktree` from a context where `get_worktree` may have been called before.

(Do I have this right so far?)

*I* know that at this point where I take the mutable reference, `get_worktree` cannot have been called before (because we only get to this branch once). Is there a way to help the borrow checker figure this out?

I believe I can "escape" from this problem with a `RefCell`, I haven't quite figured out exactly how to do that, but more importantly I suspect I will not learn The Way Of The Borrow Checker unless I try to resist `RefCell` when playing with Rust!

Comment: Here you could just use `get_or_insert_with`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=767cba9eef84a1739171a52041b1d751

Comment: Ah unfortunately that doesn't work for reasons that are hidden by my simplified example - it only works because the contents of the closure are not actually fallible (it just says so inside the string).

This was also the first thing I tried based on seeing other lazy-initialisation examples.

Comment: So then use a `match`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8a9621a4d792cdf5db6c1836dc2e6d8

Comment: Aha - I had also tried that but did not use your `worktree @ None` syntax, instead I wrote it [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8a9621a4d792cdf5db6c1836dc2e6d8). I think my issue there is I was re-borrowing a second time, whereas the `@` syntax lets you just continue to use the existing mutable reference. Do I have that right?

Comment: That sounds correct, but your "like this" link just links to my `match` example?

Comment: Oops, didn't realise I need to manually grab a new permalink. [Like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021). Can't edit my previous comment for some reason.

Thanks for the help, do you wanna promote this to an answer or shall I?

Comment: That link doesn't work either.  Never mind!  I feel like a full answer should explain the borrow checker's reasoning here... I *think* you have grasped it all correctly: the early return caused the borrow of `&self.worktree` to have lifetime of the returned `&PathBuf` and therefore precluded the simultaneous mutable borrow... but the different branches sort of also feel like something the borrow checker ought to be able to cope with, so I'll leave this for those more expert than me to explain.

Comment: I do not really understand why your example does not work, but the following modification does: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=012d4199e36898be0b0a6d4a7dbfc729 . It would be interesting to know why the borrow checker complains about your example and accepts mine.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. The  key difference seems to be that you do `if let Some(ref path) = self.worktree` whereas I did `= &self.worktree`.

Comment: Only skimmed the question but this seems like a [problem case 3 of the current borrow checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519147/double-mutable-borrow-error-in-a-loop-happens-even-with-nll-on), polonius should fix it.

Comment: A direkt [link to problem case 3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions) with a quite similar example to above.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly seems to my match my case, interesting to hear that the borrow checker will learn to handle it!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, here's one rather simple trick - just invert the condition in the getter!

```rust
    fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
        if self.worktree.is_none() {
            self.worktree.replace(PathBuf::from("<result of a fallible process>"));
        }

        Ok(self.worktree.as_ref().unwrap())
    }
```

I can't decide if I'm satisfied with this as an answer, I don't really feel I learned anything about Rust here, more like I just found a trick to solve this one specific problem...

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. The fact it does not is due to a known shortcoming in the current borrow checker, that will be fixed by the next-gen borrow checker, Polonius (it compiles if you pass the `-Z polonius` flag to nightly rustc).

Currently, we can fix it either by inventing the condition, as you've already notices (though no need for `replace()`, a simple assignment will work) or by using a `match` as @eggyal has suggested:

```rust
fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
    match &mut self.worktree {
        Some(path) => {
            // Already initialized, just return
            Ok(path)
        }
        worktree @ None => {
            // First call, initialize lazily and return.
            let path = PathBuf::from("<result of a fallible process>");
            Ok(worktree.insert(path))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, thanks for this info. At the moment it seems to be only available via `rustup default nightly`. If I use that then build with `RUSTFLAGS="-Z polonius"` I find the compiler hangs, I will wait a few days and see if whatever is causing that gets fixed in the nightly builds...

Comment: In the meantime, do you know why I find that removing the `&` from `if let Some(ref path) = &self.worktree` makes the issue go away?

Comment: @Brendan That means the borrow does not occur outside the `if let` but inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions rule out errors such as problems with the borrow checker or racing conditions from the outset, since `self.worktree` is only accessed once:

The `get_or_insert_with()` solution can be simplified as follows:

```
impl Worker {
    fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
        // Already initialized, just return
        Ok(self.worktree.get_or_insert_with(|| {
            let result = fallible_process();
            let Ok(ok) = result else {
                return Err(());
            };
            // First call, initialize lazily and return
            PathBuf::from("<ok-result of a fallible process>")
        }))
    }
}
```

---

If the `PathBuf` is abused to textually return the failure *(creepy IMHO)* then this is the solution with `get_or_insert`:

```
impl Worker {
    fn get_worktree(&mut self) -> Result<&PathBuf, ()> {
        // Already initialized, just return
        Ok(self.worktree.get_or_insert({
            let result = PathBuf::from("<result of a fallible process>");
            if result.to_str() == Some("<failure>") {
                return Err(());
            }
            // First call, initialize lazily and return
            result
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, see the first 2 comments on the original question for why

Comment: I overlooked that and changed my solution accordingly: `get_worktree()` now also returns an error.