# cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time, why different return values affect `self`

Tags: rust

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/component/ds18b20.rs:60:9
   |
37 |     pub fn temperature_read(&mut self) -> Result<f32, &str> {
   |                             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
38 |         self.onewire_reset()?;
   |         ---------------------
   |         |
   |         first mutable borrow occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
39 |
40 |         self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Skip as u8);
   |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

code:

```rust
use esp_idf_svc::hal::delay::*;
use esp_idf_svc::hal::gpio::*;
use esp_idf_svc::hal::peripheral::*;

enum CMD {
    Skip = 0xcc,
    Write = 0x4e,
    Temp = 0x44,
    Read = 0xbe,
}

pub struct Ds18b20<'a, OnewirePin>
where
    OnewirePin: Peripheral<P = OnewirePin> + InputPin + OutputPin,
{
    pin: PinDriver<'a, OnewirePin, InputOutput>,
    delay: Delay,
}

impl<'a, OnewirePin> Ds18b20<'a, OnewirePin>
where
    OnewirePin: Peripheral<P = OnewirePin> + InputPin + OutputPin,
{
    pub fn new(pin: OnewirePin, pullup: bool) -> Self {
        let mut pin = PinDriver::input_output_od(pin).unwrap();
        let delay = Delay::new_default();

        if pullup {
            pin.set_pull(Pull::Up).unwrap();
        } else {
            pin.set_pull(Pull::Floating).unwrap(); // use external pullup
        }

        Self { pin, delay }
    }

    pub fn temperature_read(&mut self) -> Result<f32, &str> {
        self.onewire_reset()?;

        self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Skip as u8);
        self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Temp as u8);

        self.onewire_reset()?;

        self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Skip as u8);
        self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Read as u8);

        let temp_l = self.onewire_byte_read();
        let temp_h = self.onewire_byte_read();

        Ok((((temp_h as i16) << 8 | (temp_l as i16)) as f32) * 0.0625)
    }

    fn onewire_reset(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
        self.pin.set_low().unwrap();
        self.delay.delay_us(600);
        self.pin.set_high().unwrap();
        self.delay.delay_us(80);

        if self.pin.is_low() {
            self.delay.delay_us(300);

            if self.pin.is_high() {
                Ok(())
            } else {
                Err("reset err")
            }
        } else {
            Err("reset err")
        }
    }

    fn onewire_byte_write(&mut self, mut byte: u8) {
        for _ in 0..8 {
            let bit = byte & 0x01 != 0;
            byte >>= 1;

            self.pin.set_low().unwrap();
            self.delay.delay_us(if bit { 5 } else { 60 });

            self.pin.set_high().unwrap();
            self.delay.delay_us(if bit { 60 } else { 5 });
        }
    }
}
```

originally used `bool` as the return value, there is no problem, changed to `Result` as the return value appeared this error.

If you put the first sentence of 'fn temperature_read' self.onewire_reset()?; 'Comment, the same error will appear in the second sentence 'self.onewire_reset()?; 'Below'self.onewire_byte_write(CMD::Skip as u8);'

I don't understand why different return values affect `self`.

https://github.com/kellerkindt/onewire/blob/master/src/lib.rs is someone else's code, which also uses similar syntax, but that is no problem.

Comment: My guess is that this is due to lifetime elision assuming that the `&str` in `Result<(), &str>` is borrowed from `&mut self`. What happens if you mark it `'static`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Here's the thing. That's good. to`fn onewire_reset(&mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str>`

Comment: it's a limitation of borrow checker, would compile with polonius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `&str`, not the `Result`.

Specifically,its the lack of a lifetime annotation.

As it is in your code, the compiler assumes that the lifetime of a `str` is going to be derived from `&mut self`, which means that while that `&str` exists `self` is considered to be borrowed.

```rust
fn onewire_reset(&mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str>
```

Should solve the problem.

See More:

- [Double mutable borrow error in a loop happens even with NLL on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519147/double-mutable-borrow-error-in-a-loop-happens-even-with-nll-on/50570026#50570026)

Comment: That explains _why_ the issue occurs, but not _how_ to fix it, which is to use explicit lifetimes on the returned value: `Result<(), &'static str>`

Comment: Here's the thing. That's good. to`fn onewire_reset(&mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str>`