# Multiple borrows error when fetching and setting a value in Struct

Tags: rust

#### Task

A simple data-structure that gets and sets a value of a field in a `struct`.

#### Issue

The following `get_or_set` function errors with

> cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

#### Code

```rust
struct MyValue<A> {
    value: Option<A>,
}

impl<A> MyValue<A> {
    fn get(&self) -> &Option<A> {
        &self.value
    }

    fn set<F: FnOnce() -> A>(&mut self, setter: F) -> &Option<A> {
        self.value = Some(setter());
        self.get()
    }

    //this function is causing borrow error
    fn get_or_set<F: FnOnce() -> A>(&mut self, setter: F) -> &Option<A> {
        match self.get() {
            None => self.set(setter),
            some @ Some(_) => some
        }
    }
}
```

#### Why does the error occur?

Following the error the issue is that I am call `self.set` a second time before the first `self.get` goes out of scope and multiple borrows are not allowed.

#### Fix:

Use `if` & `else` instead. Here I'm calling `self.get` twice which is not nice.

```rust
fn get_or_set<F: FnOnce() -> A>(&mut self, setter: F) -> &Option<A> {
    if self.get().is_some() {
        self.get()
    } else {
        self.set(setter)
    }
}
```

#### Question

How do I get the borrow check to allow the match statement to pass as well? My attempt at setting lifetimes has not succeeded.

```rust
fn get_or_set<'a, F: FnOnce() -> A + 'a>(&'a mut self, setter: F) -> &'a Option<A>
```

Comment: because match is one expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s)

Comment: (quite similar but I'm unsure it's a correct answer for this question, can you test with `-Zpolonius` ?)

Comment: @Stargateur just tested and -Zpolonius flag on nightly and it fixes this issue. I would suggest leaving this question open since they are two different problems with probably a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your function like this:

```rust
fn get_or_set1<F: FnOnce() -> A>(&mut self, setter: F) -> &Option<A> {
    match *self.get() {
        None => self.set(setter),
        _ => &self.value,
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But it's so weird. I don't get the reason behind this. The error said I borrowed the `self` twice and points to `None`'s body but calling `self` the third time with `_ => &self.value` fixes it :S

Comment: `match self.get()` creates a temp variable which references `&Option<T>` returned from `get` as a shared reference, then when you call `self.set(setter)` you try to borrow it again, mutably this time. When you deref it then the reference is not held anymore. In your `if`, you don't hold reference because you call `is_some` method and get `bool` result.
Check the second paragraph here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html

Comment: The question states that calling `self.get()` twice is "not nice", but this answer does essentially the same thing, except it inlines the second call by accessing `self.value` directly (thus breaking encapsulation, if it was intended).

Comment: @user4815162342 that's right I didn't notice that. Is `-Zpolonius` flag the only solution?

Comment: @captain-inquisitive I wouldn't count `-Zpolonius` as a solution, since it's not available on stable. That the code works with that flag indicates that the problem is not with your code but with the current borrow checker, and that the issue is likely to go away in some future release of Rust. But Polonius is still in development and there is no public schedule for when it will be ready for general use. Looking at other similar questions, it looks like calling `get()` twice is the only solution without unsafe. If you're interested with solutions with unsafe, one can probably be written too.