# How to prevent multiple mutable borrows when wrapping two different but related types in an enum?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm working with a library that offers a RAII transaction API shaped like this:

```
struct Dataset {}

struct Transaction<'a> {
    dataset: &'a mut Dataset,
}

struct Error;

impl Dataset {
    fn start_transaction(&mut self) -> Result<Transaction<'_>, Error> {
        Ok(Transaction { dataset: self }) // In real life, may also return Err.
    }
}
```

Now I want to write some wrapper code that tries to start a `Transaction` on a dataset, but if that fails because the underlying data source does not support transactions, it returns the `Dataset` as-is. (Then everything is eventually resolved to a `Dataset` through `DerefMut` implementations, but that's beside the point.)

Here's my attempt:

```
enum TransactionIfSupported<'a> {
    Transaction(Transaction<'a>),
    Dataset(&'a mut Dataset),
}

fn start_transaction_if_supported<'a>(dataset: &'a mut Dataset) -> TransactionIfSupported<'a> {
    if let Ok(txn) = dataset.start_transaction() {
        return TransactionIfSupported::Transaction(txn);
    }
    TransactionIfSupported::Dataset(dataset)
}
```

Sadly the borrow checker frowns upon it:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*dataset` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:28:37
   |
24 | fn start_transaction_if_supported<'a>(dataset: &'a mut Dataset) -> TransactionIfSupported<'a> {
   |                                   -- lifetime `'a` defined here
25 |     if let Ok(txn) = dataset.start_transaction() {
   |                      --------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
26 |         return TransactionIfSupported::Transaction(txn);
   |                ---------------------------------------- returning this value requires that `*dataset` is borrowed for `'a`
27 |     }
28 |     TransactionIfSupported::Dataset(dataset)
   |                                     ^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't quite understand why this happens. If `start_transaction` returns the `Err` variant, I'd expect any borrows from the `start_transaction` call to no longer be in scope after the `if` block. I'd expect this to hold even if there was no unconditional `return` statement inside the `if`.

What's going on and how do I resolve it?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d538933398e898788b85622dfcf24ed)

Comment: Applying the code of `start_transaction_if_supported` inline, as suggested in the link, [also works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27b8810f16d44ef79384dff37d39469e).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [the borrow checker is not smart enough to handle this case yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s). The linked question contains a solution for the `HashMap` case specifically, which will not work here because there is no `contains_key` equivalent.

Instead, we need some `unsafe` code to express it:

```
fn start_transaction_if_supported<'a, 'b>(dataset: &'b mut Dataset) -> TransactionIfSupported<'a, 'b> {
    unsafe {
        let dataset_ptr: *mut Dataset = dataset;
        if let Ok(txn) = (*dataset_ptr).start_transaction() {
            return TransactionIfSupported::Transaction(txn);
        }
        TransactionIfSupported::Dataset(&mut *dataset)
    }
}
```