# Rust BinaryTree remove method - fighting the borrow checker

Tags: rust

As part of learning Rust, I am trying to implement a simple BST and here are the relevant parts of the code. Please note that the code doesn't actually implement the remove operation. Just trying to get the thing compiling.

```
type HeapNode<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    left: HeapNode<T>,
    right: HeapNode<T>,
}

struct BinarySearchTree<T: Ord> {
    root: HeapNode<T>,
    size: usize,
}

impl<T: Ord> Node<T> {
    pub fn remove(mut root: &mut HeapNode<T>, value: &T) -> bool {
        //
        while let Some(ref mut current) = root {
            match value.cmp(&current.data) {
                std::cmp::Ordering::Less => {
                    root = &mut root.as_mut().unwrap().left;
                }
                std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => {
                    root = &mut current.right;
                    return true;
                }
                std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => return true,
            }
        }

        false
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*root` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:94:33
   |
89 |     pub fn remove(mut root: &mut HeapNode<T>, value: &T) -> bool {
   |                             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
90 |         //
91 |         while let Some(ref mut current) = root {
   |                        ---------------
   |                        |
   |                        first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        assignment requires that `root.0` is borrowed for `'1`
...
94 |                     root = &mut root.as_mut().unwrap().left;
   |                                 ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

I understand that exclusive access more than once is not allowed, but the error only comes if I add the below line under Greater enum branch:

```
root = &mut current.right;
```

Code compiles if I comment this out. That time compiler stops caring about more than one exclusive access ?
I definitely feel like the compiler thinks I am holding onto a data that gets overwritten somewhere, but just cant reason about it.

But this compiles:

```
pub fn remove(mut root: &mut HeapNode<T>, value: &T) -> bool {
        //
        while let Some(ref mut current) = root {
            match value.cmp(&current.data) {
                std::cmp::Ordering::Less => {
                    root = &mut root.as_mut().unwrap().left;
                }
                std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => {
                    root = &mut root.as_mut().unwrap().right;
                    return true;
                }
                std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => return true,
            }
        }

        false
    }
```

So, I do not need help with making it compile, but rather want someone to explain to me what the compiler is thinking so that I could make reasons to convert a non working code to a working one like above.

I am using Rust version 1.73.

Comment: This is a known limitation of the current borrow checker and [works with polonius](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/fo9dYnhWM) (Or when just using `&mut current.left/right` to begin with). It's [problem case #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s).

Comment: Thanks. But I still do not understand why it works when I use "root.as_mut().unwrap().left/right" for both Less and Greater branches. Shouldn't "as_mut" on root be disallowed as we have already borrowed it mutably in the while let ?

Comment: In that version you're not using the borrow `current` inside the `match` and as such it only needs to live to the `value.cmp(&current.data)` as opposed to having to be live inside one branch of the `match` and with that to the end of the function. Or in other words with the current borrow model you can mutably borrow either `current` or `root` across the `match` branches, but not both.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate instead, I feel all I've contributed is a description how that other question applies to your code. Feel free to leave this up as a signpost though.