# Rust Borrow Checker: Multiple references although returning early

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

If have the following Rust Code:

```rust
fn bst_impl<'a>(graph: &Graph, max_k: &u16, vc: &'a mut HashSet<u16>) -> Option<&'a HashSet<u16>> {

    if vc.len() > *max_k as usize {
        return None;
    }

    let mut edge: Option<(u16, u16)> = None;

    'outer: for (u, edges) in graph.adj_list.iter().enumerate() {
        if vc.contains(&(u as u16)) {
            continue;
        }
        for v in edges {
            if !vc.contains(&(*v as u16)) {
                edge = Some((u as u16, *v));
                break 'outer;
            }
        }
    }

    match edge {
        None => {
            return Some(vc);
        }
        Some((u, v)) => {

            vc.insert(u);
            if let Some(result) = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc) {
                return Some(result);
            } else {
                vc.insert(v);
                if let Some(result) = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc) {
                    return Some(result);
                }
            }

            return None;
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting part is here:

```rust
vc.insert(u);
if let Some(result) = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc) {
    return Some(result);
} else {
    vc.insert(v);
    if let Some(result) = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc) {
        return Some(result);
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*vc` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/bst.rs:43:17
   |
13 | fn bst_impl<'a>(graph: &Graph, max_k: &u16, vc: &'a mut HashSet<u16>) -> Option<&'a HashSet<u16>> {
   |             -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
40 |             if let Some(result) = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc) {
   |                                                          -- first mutable borrow occurs here
41 |                 return Some(result);
   |                        ------------ returning this value requires that `*vc` is borrowed for `'a`
42 |             } else {
43 |                 vc.insert(u);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

In my understanding, the rust compiler should be smart enough to know that the second mutable borrow wont happen if the condition is fulfilled and the the result is returned. What do I do wrong?

Edit:
In this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s), the main point for my problem is that it should work, but it does not due to the limitations of the current bower checker. The question is: How can I possibly restructure my code, to make it work with the current borrow checker without additional (possible) expensive cloning.

Comment: The same is true, if I explicitely block scope the questionable variables

`
            {
                vc.insert(u);
                let vc1 = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc);
                if vc1.is_some() {
                    return vc1;
                }
            }

            {
                vc.insert(u);
                let vc1 = bst_impl(graph, max_k, vc);
                if vc1.is_some() {
                    return vc1;
                }
            }
`

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Sadly, this is a known bug/limitation in the current borrow checker. There is no reason this code _shouldn't_ work, but right now it doesn't. The linked duplicate has some workarounds.

Comment: The answer cited applies to where an immutable needs to be mutated, and is slightly different in context.  In this case, the issue is you're doing an insert _where it could be being processed recursively_.  You may need to `clone` vc in `Some`

Comment: @jimmy-smith, as far, as I understood it, i cannot clone the result in `Some(result)` as then the lifetime of the cloned results would be insufficient but I want to prevent cloning the input vc due to perfomance reasons (if this is a valid concern)